# how do I select value with the result of count(*) group by?

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

[image]

Each keyword should have 4 pieces of data.

And I want to select the keywords that are less than 4 pieces of data.

I used `select count(*) from mytable group by keyword` to achieve something like this:

[image]

how can I select the keywords based on the count(*) result?

Here I want the keyword `b` from the result grid.

I am new to sql, thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a `HAVING` clause: `HAVING COUNT(*) < 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to filter result by aggregation functions (like `count`) you need to use `having`, for example:

```
select keyword, count(*)
from mytable
group by keyword
having count(*) < 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Just include `having` clause something like that :

```
select keyword
from mytable t
group by keyword
having count(*) < 4;
```